# I'm trying to learn spring boot for a project. I want to consume an api which requires auth token. How do I authenticate my token using spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication

I am trying to develop a web application using SPRING-BOOT that requires me to consume an external API to authenticate the access token. How do I pass that token in my code?

Comment: Please take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101250/sending-get-request-with-authentication-headers-using-resttemplate)!

Comment: Hello! Please provide your attempt to tackle the question such that others may tweak and suggest improvements. Here is some documentation on how to write a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.