# How to add the header into RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, token

I am trying to add a header into the restTemplate, with one of its methods `exchange`.
In header i am putting the token access, which we can access with.
The error i am getting is that i am not Authorized, 401 status is giving back . Any advices what i am doing wrong?

```
 HttpHeaders headersAuth = new HttpHeaders();
        headersAuth.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        HttpEntity<?> entityAuth =  new HttpEntity<>(headersAuth);
        String urlTemplateAuth = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("some url")
                .encode()
                .toUriString();
        Map<String,String> queryParamsAuth = new HashMap<>();
        queryParamsAuth.put("Authorization",tokenValue); //here is my token access


            ResponseEntity <UserGetPhoneDto> userGetPhoneDtoResponseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(urlTemplateAuth,HttpMethod.GET,entityAuth,UserGetPhoneDto.class,queryParamsAuth); 
//here i am getting error of 401 status
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending GET request with Authentication headers using restTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101250/sending-get-request-with-authentication-headers-using-resttemplate)

Comment: You want to set a header but fill the parameter map. Use `headersAuth.setBearerAuth(token)` instead of map or parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set token to header yet, you set it in your query parameter.
You can use `headersAuth.setBearerAuth()` to set bearer token, or use `setBasicAuth()` to set username and password.
Another way to put it in your header:

```
headersAuth.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token);
```

OAuth2 server can retrieve your token in query parameter with name 'access_token' too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't put the token into the request header.

```
    HttpHeaders headersAuth = new HttpHeaders();
    
    headersAuth.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    
    String urlTemplateAuth = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("some url")
            .encode()
            .toUriString();
    Map<String,String> queryParamsAuth = new HashMap<>();
    headersAuth.put("Authorization",tokenValue); //here is put it into headers
    HttpEntity<?> entityAuth =  new HttpEntity<>(headersAuth);//build entity by header
   //exchange...
```

You can read this document to learn more about http.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP