# Postman - How to see request with headers and body data with variables substituted

Tags: postman

I am using the [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) Chrome plugin to invoke HTTP requests for software testing. I use the [Environments](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/environments) feature with Environment and Global Variables to substitute variables in my requests headers and body.

The variable substitution is working correctly (I can tell as the responses from the HTTP Server indicate that).

However, I would like to be able to see the Request Header and Body values **AFTER** the variables have been substituted. How can I do that?

Comment: @borislemke has the right answer since the deprecation of the chrome plugin.

Comment: Log body and header in your software ^^

Comment: Postman Chrome extension has been deprecated.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Update 2018-12-12 - Chrome App v Chrome Plugin** - Most recent updates at top

With the [deprecation of the Postman Chrome App](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/11/01/goodbye-postman-chrome-app/), assuming that you are now using the [Postman Native App](https://www.getpostman.com/apps), the options are now:

1. Hover over variables with mouse
2. Generate "Code" button/link
3. Postman Console

See below for full details on each option.

Personally, I still go for **2) Generate "Code" button/link** as it allows  me to see the variables without actually having to send.

Demo Request
[image: Demo Request]

Demo Environment
[image: Demo Environment]

1) Hover over variables with mouse
[image: Hover over variables with mouse]

2) Generate "Code" button/link
[image: Generate "Code" button/link]

3) Postman Console
[image]

**Update: 2016-06-03**

Whilst the method described above does work, in practice, I now normally use the  "Generate Code" link on the Postman Request screen. The generated code, no matter what code language you choose, contains the substituted variables. Hitting the "Generate Code" link is just faster, additionally, you can see the substituted variables without actually making the request.

**Original Answer below**

To see the substituted variables in the Headers and Body, you need to use Chrome Developer tools. To enable Chrome Developer Tools from within Postman do the following, as per [http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/06/13/debugging-postman-requests](http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/06/13/debugging-postman-requests/)/.

I have copied the instructions from the link above in case the link gets broken in the future:

1. Type chrome://flags inside your Chrome URL window
2. Search for “packed” or try to find the “Enable debugging for packed apps”
3. Enable the setting
4. Restart Chrome

> You can access the Developer Tools window by right clicking anywhere
>   inside Postman and selecting “inspect element”. You can also go to
>   chrome://inspect/#apps and then click “inspect” just below
>   requester.html under the Postman heading.
>
> Once enabled, you can use the Network Tools tab for even more
>   information on your requests or the console while writing test
>   scripts. If something goes wrong with your test scripts, it’ll show up
>   here.

Comment: When I do this, the Request URL (in DevTools: Network: <FileName>: General) is like `filesystem:chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop/temporary/response.html`. This might be because I am also using the Interceptor extension, to see cookies. How can i have it all? URL with substitutions, request headers, request cookies, request body, response status, headers, and body?

Comment: Promoted that reply to [it's own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34229865/how-can-i-see-postman-proper-request-url-and-body).

Comment: Okidok, code snippets - [Generating code snippets in Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/#generating-code-snippets-in-postman).

Comment: Unfortunately on my version (it doesn't seem to have version numbers but I'm on Ubuntu), both the console and code view are missing the ampersands in the request body.

Comment: The code generation view is certainly the nicest way to view the request with variables substituted, however, if you have pre-request scripts that alter the request, the changes it makes will not show up here, and you will need to use the console to see what was really sent.

Answer (score 353):

As of now, Postman comes with its own "Console." Click the terminal-like icon on the bottom left to open the console. Send a request, and you can inspect the request from within Postman's console.

[image]

In the modern version, it currently it looks like:

[image]

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me in the native Windows app.

Comment: Since the deprecation of the chrome plugin, this is now the correct answer.

Comment: This is not a raw request.

Comment: @PhilipRego Log entries now contain a "Show raw log" button in the top right corner. Click it to display the raw request.

Answer (score 34):

If, like me, you are still using the browser version (which will be deprecated soon), have you tried the "Code" button?

[image]

This should generate a snippet which contains the entire request Postman is firing. You can even choose the language for the snippet. I find it quite handy when I need to debug stuff.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add complementary information:
In postman app you may use the "request" object to see your subsituted input data. (refer to https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox in paragraph "Request/response related properties",
ie.

```
console.log("header : " + request.headers["Content-Type"]);
console.log("body : " + request.data);
console.log("url : " + request.url);
```

I didn't test for header substitution but it works for url and body.

Alex

Answer (score 5):

You can easily check the content of requests and responses with help of the postman console.

Here is a nice short video explanation [How to debug postman request explained](https://youtu.be/462Lurgb-6E).

You can see below the snippet of how the log will show data.

You can check above video for learning how to log custom information.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On web version, if you click code tab on the right, code snippet will appear with multiple language and format choices.

[image: Tab]

[image: Snippet]

Comment: very helpful answer. It would be more helpful if you inlined the images like the other answers, which you can do if you simply change `[Tab][1]` to `[![Tab][1]][1]`

Comment: @gMale thanks a lot. I thought i couldn't do it because i don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Even though they are separate windows but the request you send from Postman, it's details should be available in network tab of developer tools.
Just make sure you are not sending any other http traffic during that time, just for clarity.

Comment: I just tried that and nothing from Postman goes into the network tab of the developer tools

Answer (score 0):

If you paste this code to the test of your request you should see a 'Copy to clipboard' button in the 'Visualize' tab that will copy the request with the substituted variables.

```js
var request = pm.request.body.raw.replace(/\n/g,' ').replace(/\t/g,' ');
var html = '''<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <h5>REQUEST</h5>
      <div>
        <textarea rows="20" cols="40" style="min-width:700px;min-height:300px" id="copyText">
          $$REQUEST$$
        </textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="copyButton" type="button" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#copyText"
        style="background:green;color:white;">
        Copy to clipboard
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
<script>
  var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.copyButton');
  clipboard.on('success', function (e) {
    e.clearSelection();
    e.trigger.textContent = 'Copiado!';
    window.setTimeout(function () { e.trigger.textContent = 'Copy to Clipboard'; }, 2000);
  });
  clipboard.on('error', function (e) {
    e.clearSelection();
    e.trigger.textContent = 'No copiado';
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      e.trigger.textContent = 'Copy to Clipboard';
    }, 2000);
  }); 
</script>'''

var html = html.replace("$$REQUEST$$", request);

pm.visualizer.set(html, pm.request)
```

You can also set the html as a variable to make the code cleaner.