# Using Postman to test API, where is the Postman call?

Tags: json, postman

I have a web API that I am using Postman to test.  When I click on the "SEND" button, Postman sends data to the web API so I am able to test the web API but I would like to view the data that Postman is sending to the web API.  How can I do view this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793629/ sounds like what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to view the raw request, one way would be to select the Code option and then choose Curl. The Code option is under the Send button, right of the Params/Tests menu bar.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTTP GET/DELETE, you can find data in URL of request and HTTP Header. If you are using POST, then you can find in Request body.