# Django Rest Framework showing a field error even after uploading the file to that field with Postman during creating the post

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I am new to DRF, I have this serializer, but I am not able to create the post as it keeps showing me this in postman even after uploading an image to that field. In normal django, this PostImage model has a foreign key relation to Post and I use a formset to upload multiple images.

```
{
"postimage": [
    "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Can someone help me to resolve this and tell me how it works?

serializer.py

```
class PostImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = PostImage
       fields = ['id','post', 'images',]  

class PostCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    postimage = PostImageSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id','title', 'image', 'postimage',]
```

views.py

```
def create_post_api_view(request):
    user = request.user
    post = Post(user=user)
    serializer = PostCreateSerializer(post, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

UPDATE:

payload.

```
Authorization: Token XXXX

: 
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.2
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 066c9a26-af76-4a44-9e9f-a3326050fa"
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------554448102853056787089432
Content-Length: 123293

Request Body
title: "Another Trial api posts"
image: {…}
_events: {}
_eventsCount: 3
_readableState: {…}
autoDestroy: false
awaitDrain: 0
buffer: {…}
head: null
length: 0
tail: null
decoder: null
defaultEncoding: "utf8"
destroyed: true
emitClose: false
emittedReadable: false
encoding: null
endEmitted: true
ended: true
flowing: true
highWaterMark: 65536
length: 0
needReadable: false
objectMode: false
paused: false
pipes: null
pipesCount: 0
readableListening: false
reading: false
readingMore: false
resumeScheduled: false
sync: false
autoClose: true
bytesRead: 5473
closed: true
fd: null
flags: "r"
mode: 438
path: "C:\Users\danny\Desktop\test images\cat.jpg"
readable: false

postimage: [2]
0: {…}
_events: {}
_eventsCount: 3
_readableState: {…}
autoDestroy: false
awaitDrain: 0
buffer: {…}
decoder: null
defaultEncoding: "utf8"
destroyed: true
emitClose: false
emittedReadable: false
encoding: null
endEmitted: true
ended: true
flowing: true
highWaterMark: 65536
length: 0
needReadable: false
objectMode: false
paused: false
pipes: null
pipesCount: 0
readableListening: false
reading: false
readingMore: false
resumeScheduled: false
sync: false
autoClose: true
bytesRead: 7350
closed: true
fd: null
flags: "r"
mode: 438
path: "C:\Users\danny\Desktop\test images\041520_mt_supernova_feat-1028x579.jpg"
readable: false
1: {…}
_events: {}
_eventsCount: 3
_readableState: {…}
autoDestroy: false
awaitDrain: 0
buffer: {…}
decoder: null
defaultEncoding: "utf8"
destroyed: true
emitClose: false
emittedReadable: false
encoding: null
endEmitted: true
ended: true
flowing: true
highWaterMark: 65536
length: 0
needReadable: false
objectMode: false
paused: false
pipes: null
pipesCount: 0
readableListening: false
reading: false
readingMore: false
resumeScheduled: false
sync: false
autoClose: true
bytesRead: 109530
closed: true
fd: null
flags: "r"
mode: 438
path: "C:\Users\danny\Desktop\test images\Tischvase-X-Form-VX-silber-dek-Holst-Porzellan.jpg"
readable: false
Response Headers
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2020 10:09:18 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.2
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept, Accept-Language, Cookie
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 41
Content-Language: en

Response Body
{"postimage":["This field is required."]}
```

updated createserializer

```
class PostCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
images = serializers.ImageField()
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ['id','title','image', 'images',]

def create(self,validated_data):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    title = validated_data['title']
    image = self.context['request'].FILES.get('image')
    images = self.context['request'].FILES.get('images')
    m1 = Post(
        title=title,
        image=image,
        user=user
    )
    m1.save()
    m2 = PostImage(
        post=m1,
        images=images
    )
    m2.save()
    validated_data['images']=m2.images
    return validated_data
```

Response based on the last edit

```
{
"title": "Another Trial api posts",
"image": null,
"images": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/posts/postimage/Tischvase-X-Form-VX-silber-dek-Holst-Porzellan.jpg"
```

}

now the other image is null..

Thanks

Comment: So what is the payload that postman is creating?

Comment: Is that the json output the postman is showing?

Comment: Yes, and please shorten any excessively long text data (like base64 encoded image data, that you would have if you really are uploading images).

Comment: Ok.thank you..I guess the output postman is showing, I already have that in the question, the first part with the 'postimage'. It also shows a status error HTTP 400 bad request.

Comment: No, that's the response. The payload is the request. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47278422

Comment: Thanks for that new info.. I found that and has updated the question. Its a bit long though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should write your own create method for your serializer. Something like this

models

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.field1)

class MyModel2(models.Model):
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    foreignkeytomymodel = models.ForeignKey(MyModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.field2)
```

serializers

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field2 = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    image = serializers.ImageField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1','field2', 'image']

    def create(self,validated_data):
        field1 = validated_data['field1']
        field2 = validated_data['field2']
        image = self.context['request'].FILES.get('image')
        m1 = MyModel(
            field1=field1
        )
        m1.save()
        m2 = MyModel2(
            field2=field2,
            image=image,
            foreignkeytomymodel=m1
        )
        m2.save()
        validated_data['field2']=m2.field2
        validated_data['image']=m2.image
        return validated_data
```

views

```
serializer = MyModelSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request':request})
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Update Based on your Serializer -

```
class PostCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id','title','image', 'images',]

    def create(self,validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        title = validated_data['title']
        image = self.context['request'].FILES.get('image')
        images = self.context['request'].FILES.get('images')
        m1 = Post(
            title=title,
            image=image,
            user=user
        )
        m1.save()
        m2 = PostImage(
            post=m1,
            images=images
        )
        m2.save()
        validated_data['image']=m1.image
        validated_data['images']=m2.images
        return validated_data
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Should this be for PostSerializer in this case?
also can you tell me what MyModel12 is?

Comment: Thank you..let me try this way!

Comment: Hello I tried, now the problem is only 1 model data is getting saved and the other is showing null

Comment: Post model.. I tried without the user, but it was showing a user_id not null constraint error or something.

Comment: please check the last portion of my updated answer. may be that helps.

Comment: Thanks it works in a way and I have updated the question with the response from postman. But only 1 image is getting uploaded instead of 2 when I upload 2 images...is there a way to change that?

Comment: please add this line also validated_data['image']=m1.image

Comment: Yes, now that works, thank you.
can i ask you one more thing?? I usually have the 'images' to upload multiple images but here even if I upload 2 to that field its only saving 1 image, so should I use a for loop to loop through the field and save images?

Comment: yes we can use loop. but it will be good if you start a new thread as this comment section is getting extended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218703/discussion-between-danny-and-sst).