# Error: No attribute when upload video successful in Jmeter

Tags: automation, jmeter

I upload video via Jmeter. It is successful, but when I check again video is object has no attribute 'video'.

1. I upload video by HTTP Request:
   [Upload video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXSkt.png)
   Response headers:
   [Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KI0J.png)
   [Response data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25kC4.png)
2. I uploaded the video via postman and it still works fine.
   [Upload video via Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8xZu.png)

I also tried using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, however I cannot run the test again.
Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing different behaviour with Postman and JMeter it means that you're sending a different request using JMeter.

You need to figure out what are the differences by either

- inspecting [Postman's console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793629/postman-how-to-see-request-with-headers-and-body-data-with-variables-substitut) and [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file with [enabled JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for [HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/)
- capturing requests from Postman and JMeter using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Once you determine what are the differences and amend JMeter configuration to eliminate them you should see the same responses

It's also possible to record the request from Postman using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, just remember to:

- [Import JMeter's certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

  [image]
- Copy the file you're going to upload to JMeter's "bin" folder
- [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/)

  [image]